# Schedule Cron expression not valid?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm creating an [AWS CloudWatch](https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-west-2#rules:action=create) rule, using the *Schedule Cron expression*: `30 10 * * 2,5 *`, namely - every Tuesday and Friday on 10:30 UTC.

However, AWS gives me

```
There was an error while saving rule Snapshot_EBS_disk.
Details: Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid..
```

Any idea what's wrong with my expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of day-of-month or day-of-week must be `?`. So to make your cron expression valid you would use the following:

`30 10 ? * 3,6 *`

Also note that Tuesday and Friday are 3 and 6 respectively